# Cookie generation bug : do not set [ PHP ]

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I generate a string with this code :

```
$order = new Order();
$orderReference = $order->generateNewOrderReference();

echo $orderReference;
setcookie("orderReference", $orderReference, time() + 30*24*60*60, '/', null, false, true);
echo 'papa';

public function generateNewOrderReference() {
    $orderReference = strtoupper(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4)));

    while ($this->orderReferenceAlreadyExists($orderReference)) {
        $orderReference = strtoupper(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4)));
    }

    return $orderReference;
}

public function orderReferenceAlreadyExists($orderReference) {
    $statement = $this->database->prepare("SELECT order_reference FROM $this->table_name WHERE order_reference = :order_reference");
    $statement->bindParam(':order_reference',$orderReference);
    $statement->execute();

    if (!empty($statement->fetch())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The generation works because I have this when I see my view :
6239B30Bpapa

But I don't understand why the cookie is not set in my localhost :/. Does someone have an idea please ?

It's looks like any cookie can be set here.

More over I have a MVC archietcture and the code shared represents page model

In which each controller redirect to router with pageName

My router scheme looks like this :

- processing algo
- include model
- include view

Sorry fo my english. I'm French.

When I put this code into my controller, cookie can be set. So, I think that if there is already html code, I can't generate cookie. Is it true ?

Comment: _“So, I think that if there is already html code, I can't generate cookie. Is it true ?”_ - yes, and if you had enabled proper PHP error reporting, then it should be telling you that you tried to send a header after output was already generated.

Comment: Ok thank you, i don't know this PHP error reporting, I'm gonna check how to activate it. Thank you for you for help :)